# Choosing the best way to implement a reusable button

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently thinking on what is the best way to have a reusable button that doesn't have to rebuild its widget however will have the ability to pass parameters when I call it on a statefulwidget?

Currently, I do have class based widget...

```
class DynamicButtonStyle {
  static customButtonStyle({
    String? buttonTitle,
    TextStyle? buttonStyle,
    VoidCallback? onPressedFunction,
  }) {
    return ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: onPressedFunction,
        child: Text(
          buttonTitle ?? '',
          style: buttonStyle ?? const TextStyle(),
        ));
  }
}
```

and this class based widget, I call this in a `StatefulWidget` wherein I can pass a parameters so It can be customizable when calling in every screen page of my flutter app...

login_page.dart <-- // calling inside of this statefulwidget file...

```
DynamicButtonStyle.customButtonStyle(
  buttonTitle: "Register now",
  onPressedFunction: testFunction,
),
```

Or is it best yet to just create a `StatelessWidget` of that button? or are they the same? If it's best to create a `StatelessWidget` of the button, can I pass a parameter to make it dynamic (size,height,color) when I call it? Can you also provide a sample code for it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Here's an example of how you could implement a stateless button widget with customizable properties:**

```
class MyOutlineButoon extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyOutlineButoon(
      {Key? key,
      required this.text,
      this.margin = const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
      this.height = 0,
      this.width = double.infinity,
      this.onPressed,
      this.textColor,
      this.textSize = 13, 
      this.leadingChild, 
      this.trailingChild,
      })
      : super(key: key);
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry margin;
  final double height;
  final double width;
  final void Function()? onPressed;
  final String text;
  final Color? textColor;
  final double textSize;
  final Widget? trailingChild;
  final Widget? leadingChild;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: margin,
      child: OutlinedButton(
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            fixedSize: Size(width, height),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12))),
        onPressed: onPressed,
        child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
         Padding(
           padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: leadingChild == null ? 0.0 : 10),
           child: leadingChild,
         ),
          Text(text,
              style: GoogleFonts.dmMono(
                  color: textColor ?? UIColorConstant.nativeGrey,
                  fontSize: textSize)),
                  trailingChild ?? const SizedBox.shrink(),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**This is example how I use it:**

```
               MyOutlineButoon(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 45,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                  text: "Sign in with google",
                  leadingChild: 
                   Image.asset(UIAssetConstants.googleButtonImage),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    await context.read<SignUpCubit>().loginWithGoogle();
                  },
                )
```